# Use arrow keys to rotate refrence system in openGL

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, opengl, function-pointers, glut

This is the code written in the book `openGL SuperBible` to create a Spring-Shaped Path of Points on the screen:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <gl\glut.h>
#include <gl\GLU.h>
#include <gl\GL.h>
#include <math.h>


// Define a constant for the value of PI
#define GL_PI 3.1415f



void ChangeSize(GLsizei , GLsizei );  
void SetupRC();
void RenderScene(void);


int main(int argc, CHAR* argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutCreateWindow("Points Example");
    glutDisplayFunc(RenderScene);
    glutReshapeFunc(ChangeSize);
    SetupRC();
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}

// Change viewing volume and viewport. Called when window is resized
void ChangeSize(GLsizei w, GLsizei h)
{
   GLfloat nRange = 100.0f;
   // Prevent a divide by zero
   if(h == 0)
       h = 1;
   // Set Viewport to window dimensions
   glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
   // Reset projection matrix stack
   glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
   glLoadIdentity();
   // Establish clipping volume (left, right, bottom, top, near, far)
   if (w <= h)
       glOrtho (-nRange, nRange, -nRange*h/w, nRange*h/w, -nRange, nRange);
   else
       glOrtho (-nRange*w/h, nRange*w/h, -nRange, nRange, -nRange, nRange);
   // Reset Model view matrix stack
   glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
   glLoadIdentity();
}

// This function does any needed initialization on the rendering context
void SetupRC()
{
    // Black background
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f );
   // Set drawing color to green
   glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
}

// Called to draw scene
void RenderScene(void)
{
   GLfloat x,y,z,angle;
   int xRot,yRot; // Storage for coordinates and angles
   xRot = 45;
   yRot = 45;
   // Clear the window with current clearing color
   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
   // Save matrix state and do the rotation
   glPushMatrix();
   glRotatef(xRot, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
   glRotatef(yRot, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
   // Call only once for all remaining points
   glBegin(GL_POINTS);
   z = -50.0f;
   for(angle = 0.0f; angle <= (2.0f*GL_PI)*3.0f; angle += 0.1f)
   {
       x = 50.0f*sin(angle);
       y = 50.0f*cos(angle);
      // Specify the point and move the Z value up a little
      glVertex3f(x, y, z);
      z += 0.5f;
    }
   // Done drawing points
   glEnd();
   // Restore transformations
   glPopMatrix();
   // Flush drawing commands
   glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

In fact by setting xRot=yRot=45 degrees, I have reached this shape.
[image]
But in the book it is told:
**When this program is run, all you see is a circle
of points because you are initially looking directly down the z-axis. To see the effect, use
the arrow keys to spin the drawing around the x- and y-axes.**
This means that we should have some code using arrow keys to increase and decrease the value of xRot and yRot. I have made some effort to do that.

1-Writing a function:

```
void _cdecl keyboard(int key ,int xRot,int yRot)
{
    switch (key)
    {
    case GLUT_KEY_PAGE_UP:
        yRot++;
    case GLUT_KEY_PAGE_DOWN:
        yRot--;
    case GLUT_KEY_HOME:
        xRot--;
    case GLUT_KEY_END:
        xRot++;
    }
}
```

2-Its prototype at top of the code:

```
void _cdecl keyboard(int,int,int);
```

3-adding these two lines of code to the body of the function `RenderScene`:

```
GLint key = GLUT_KEY_PAGE_UP;  
glutSpecialFunc(keyboard(key,xRot,yRot));
```

But I'm not sure it will work. The code gets the error:

```
error C2664: 'glutSpecialFunc' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'void' to 'void (__cdecl *)(int,int,int)'
```

and I don't know how to return the changed value of `xRot` and `yRot` to the caller function because the compiler doesn't let me to define `Pass by referrence` parameters and the argument of `glutSpecialFunc` is a pointer to a void function!

**Edited section of my question**
as jblocksom suggested I changed the code to something like this:
1-defining and initializing global variables just before the main starts:

```
int xRot = 0;
int yRot = 0;
```

2- calling glutSpecialFunc somewhere in main

```
glutSpecialFunc(keyboard);
glutDisplayFunc(RenderScene);
glutReshapeFunc(ChangeSize);
```

3- altering the code in keyboard function

```
void keyboard(int keyParam ,int mx,int my)
{
    switch (keyParam)
    {
    case GLUT_KEY_PAGE_UP:
        my++;
    case GLUT_KEY_PAGE_DOWN:
        my--;
    case GLUT_KEY_HOME:
        mx--;
    case GLUT_KEY_END:
        mx++;
    }
    glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

No compile and run-time error. But it does not work. I think this is because when I call `glutSpecialFunc(keyboard)`, the function uses coordinates of mouse and keypress as the input argument so any increment or decrement is applied on the mouse coordinates not `xRot` or `yRot` which will be used in `glRotatef(xRot, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)` or `glRotatef(yRot, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f)` so when calling the two latter the `xRot` and `yRot` is still equal to zero and there will be no rotation.**I need to pass `xRot` and `yRot` to the function `keyboard` but how???**
Even writing the function as:

```
void keyboard(int keyParam ,int mx,int my)
{
    switch (keyParam)
    {
    case GLUT_KEY_PAGE_UP:
        yRot++;
    case GLUT_KEY_PAGE_DOWN:
        yRot--;
    case GLUT_KEY_HOME:
        xRot--;
    case GLUT_KEY_END:
        xRot++;
    }
    glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

and calling it in the form `glutSpecialFunc(keyboard)` will not any difference!!!

Answer (score 3):

`glutSpecialFunc` registers a callback with GLUT to be called when the user hits one of the arrow keys; the function you give it, `keyboard`, is not something you would call yourself. This is why you can't return anything from it. To get data out of the callback you'll need to set a global variable.

You'll want to call `glutSpecialFunc` somewhere in `main` where the other GLUT callbacks are set (eg `glutRenderFunc`). To get past the compile error, you'll call it like this:

```
glutSpecialFunc(keyboard);
```

which tells GLUT to call `keyboard()` with the key and mouse position.

Make the `xRot` and `yRot` variables referred to in `RenderScene` global.

Change the function signature of `keyboard` to not use `xRot` and `yRot` as variable names so that it will refer to the global ones:

```
void _cdecl keyboard(int key, int mx, int my)
```

You'll also probably need a call to `glutPostRedisplay()` at the end of `keyboard`, this will tell GLUT to redraw the scene.

Hopefully after that it should work, good luck!

Comment: thanks @jblocksom but see the edited section of my question. I hope you will help me.